# Не работает второй цикл

Tags: php, циклы

Здравствуйте, есть код

```
$zapros=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
$data=mysql_fetch_assoc($zapros);
do {    } while ($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($zapros));
do {    } while ($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($zapros));
```

2 цикл не исполняется, только первый проходит, в чем причина может быть? Спасибо

Comment: [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

Comment: Спасибо, а вот вопрос, как в каждом запросе mysqli_query не открывать соединение с БД? 
mysqli_query=($link, $query);

Comment: mysqli_query=($link, $query); в данной строке вы не открываете соединение, а ссылаетесь на уже открытое соединения для Вашей сессии.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc   читаем доки

Возвращает ассоциативный массив, соответсвующий полученному ряду и сдвигает вперед внутренний указатель результата.

Первым циклом вы выбираете все записи и сдвигаете указатель в конец . в итоге при повторном вызове ничего не вернёт так как указатель стоит в конце.